# Tensorflow 2.14, GPU not getting recognized

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am running a model with a Nvidia GPU, I have:

`Python 3.10` and
`tensorflow 2.14`

However, tensorflow is not recgnising the GPU. When I run the below code, I do not see my GPU:

`print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))`

I tried installing Python 3.7 so that I could use tensorflow-gpu since that was not available with Python 3.10. However, this threw an error.

Is there any way to use the new version of tensorflow and run it on the GPU?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your CUDA version with "nvcc -V", Tensorflow still does not seem to support CUDA12.

Also, do not use Tensorflow-gpu, it is an old product that has been deprecated for a long time.